# Как можно сделать чтобы к первому images добавлял класс active, а остальным нет внутри цикла?

Tags: php, циклы, codeigniter, условия

```
<?php foreach ($images as $val):?>
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="<?=base_url()?>uploads/slaid_images/<?=$val->name?>" alt="">
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Как можно сделать чтобы к первому images добавлял класс active, а остальным нет?

Comment: Считать какой элемент сейчас в цикле.

Comment: Он же как массив идет. к нулевому добавлять имеете?

Comment: Если нужно к нулевому - добавляйте к нулевому.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простейший вариант:

```
<?php $is_first = true; ?>
<?php foreach ($images as $val):?>
    <div class="item <?=$is_first ? 'active' : ''?>">
      <img src="<?=base_url()?>uploads/slaid_images/<?=$val->name?>" alt="">
    </div>
    <?php $is_first = false; ?> 
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Если ключи массива сразу идут от 0, то и флагов никаких не надо:

```
<?php foreach ($images as $index => $val):?>
    <div class="item <?= $index === 0 ? 'active' : ''?>">
      <img src="<?=base_url()?>uploads/slaid_images/<?=$val->name?>" alt="">
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Считай какой по счёту элемент

```
<?php foreach ($images as $val):
    if(array_search($val, $images) == 0) {
        $isActive = true;
    } ?>
    <div class="item <?if($isActive):?>active<?endif?>">
        <img src="<?=base_url()?>uploads/slaid_images/<?=$val->name?>" alt="">
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: `array_search` воу-воу. Мало того что форычем по массиву идем так и в каждой итерации еще разок пройдемся.

Comment: @u_mulder пожалуйста, может напишите как правильно будет?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach ($images as $key=>$val):?>
            <div class="item <? if ($key == 0) echo "active"; ?>">
              <img src="<?=base_url()?>uploads/slaid_images/<?=$val->name?>" alt="">
            </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так, если массив имеет индексы 0, 1, 2 и т. д.:

```
<?php foreach ($images as $index => $val):?>
    <div class="item <?php if($index === 0): ?>active<?php endif ?>">
      <img src="<?=base_url()?>uploads/slaid_images/<?=$val->name?>" alt="">
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Или так, если нет:

```
<?php $index = 0; ?>
<?php foreach ($images as $val): ?>
    <div class="item<?php if($index === 0): ?> active<?php endif ?>">
      <img src="<?=base_url()?>uploads/slaid_images/<?=$val->name?>" alt="">
    </div>
    <?php $index++; ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Опционально можно использовать шаблонизатор, например, [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/), у него, помимо остальных преимуществ (например, более удобного синтактиса), есть [встроенная возможность узнать индекс итерации](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html).

Comment: помогло. Оба варианта сработали. Но выбрал первый, так как массив имеет индексы от 0... Спасибо.